# Django-South DataMigration - App available in forwards() but not backwards()?

Tags: python, django, migration, database-migration, django-south

I am writing a django south migration that depends on the model in another app, so I have included `--freeze OTHERAPPNAME` when I ran `python manage.py datamigration …`

However in the `forwards()` function I can access the other model fine (with `orm['otherappname.MyModelName']`), however in the `backwards()` step (which also depends on the model in otherappname), if I try to access `orm['otherappname.MyModelName']`, I get an error

```
*** KeyError: "The model 'mymodelname' from the app 'otherappname' is not available in this migration."
```

I can see the frozen model details in the bottom of the file. Why can't I access it?

NB: This model is created in another migration inside otherappname of which this datamigration depends on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The backwards migration actually uses the frozen ORM of the *previous* migration. It's logical when you think about it, but it's admittedly not very intuitive.

Moral: freeze the models you'll need in your datamigration in the schemamigration that proceeds it.